# BLOC library: Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe

Tags: flutter, widget, bloc

I am getting the following error:

[image]

> Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
>
> At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer
> stable.
>
> To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a
> reference to the ancestor by calling
> dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's
> didChangeDependencies() method.

Code:

```
class ProductDetailWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProductDetailWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ProductDetailWidgetState createState() => _ProductDetailWidgetState();
}

class _ProductDetailWidgetState extends State<ProductDetailWidget>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  int? countControllerValue;
  late PhysicalInventoryItem cartItem;
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    cartItem = BlocProvider.of<CartItemBloc>(context).cartItem;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       ///.....
  }
}
```

I am opening this widget by:

```
OpenContainer<bool>(
        transitionType: _transitionType,
        openBuilder: (BuildContext _, VoidCallback openContainer) {
          BlocProvider.of<CartItemBloc>(context)
              .add(CartItemSetProduct(product));
          return const ProductDetailWidget();
        },
        closedShape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(),
        closedElevation: 12.0,
        ...
```

I am using BLOC library in my project.

Tried several solutions present online but they didn't work.

Comment: Can you provide the whole widget where OpenContainer is ? And also it would be interesting to have the BlocProvider where your Bloc is declared and the relation between the two pages.

Comment: Can you post your OpenContainer implementation